# Error with java script while retrieving documents from mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Basically the idea is to get documents by calling a function from MongoDB using JavaScript (not Node.js)

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
mongo.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Database',function(err,db)
{
var result = [];
result = db.eval('getContacts("_id")',function(error, result)
{
 console.log("Error is:" +error);
 console.log("result is:"+result);
 console.log("working till here");
})
// db.close();
});
```

note: getConatcts is a DB function to get contact related details.

```
Error:  Error is:null
        result is:
        working till here
```

Comment: Show us `getContacts` code

Comment: And sorry, if you don't call it with Node how do you think to call the script?